# Complex Mongo Update

Tags: mongodb

The collection is like:

`{
    'id'    :   'xxx',
    'items' :   [
            {
                'index'    : 1,
                'on'    : '' 
            },
            {
                'index'    : 2,
                'on'    : '' 
            }
    ]
}`

I can do the update like:

`collection.update(
    {
        'id' :  'xxxx',
        'items.index'  : '2'
    },
    {
        '$set' : {
        'on' : 'true'
    } 
)`

However, the problem is that if I want to have multi-items in one document to update (each item might have different values of the key "on"). Then I have to do a loop.

Is there a way to update all in one call?

Comment: I assume you accidently left out the positional operator youd need there. The answer is not yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({id:'xxx', items:{$elemMatch:{index:2}}}, {$set:{'items.$.on':true}})
```

Comment: Writing a single line of code and not explaining it is about as useful as...well something that's not. WHat makes you think this will work?

Comment: I tested and it worked. I was planning to add some explanations based on questions. but there is none.

Comment: What it updates all matching subodcuments? Multiple ones? Despite the JIRA I posted above?